# How to turn off USB sharing on Android (Archos 70) - Installing Android Market

Tags: usb

I'm trying to install the Android market to my Archos 70.

```
1. Load the update.img to the root of your A7HT.
2. Turn off USB sharing and you will be prompted to install an update.
3. Click install and A7 will reboot
4. Install the update and eventually go back to the setup screen
5. Go into settings, turn on WiFi and connect to your router
6. Once it is connected:
a. Open any of the Google apps (market, Gmail, Calendar)
b. Go through the Google setup screens.
c. Upon completion install: contacts.apk and GoogleContactsProvider.apk.
```

http://wiki.archosfans.com/index.php?title=Archos_7HT_Firmware_Knightsdominion_V3_Google_Market

How do I turn off USB sharing? I've disconnected and unmounted the Archos from my machine but it doesn't ask me to update; I've also tried rebooting it.

Comment: It could be referring to USB debug mode. Go to `Settings -> Applications -> Development` to turn that off.

Comment: I don't belive that's what it's referring to. I had checked those settings and it was already turned off by default.

Comment: OK.  In that case it does sound like simple disconnection from the PC.  Are you currently running the exact same software (OS version, kernel version, etc.) that they were in the guide you're following?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do this for the Archos 70.  Do you have the Archos **70 Internet Tablet** or the Archos **7 Home Tablet**?  The link you have is for the Archos 7 Home Tablet, which is an older model.  If you in fact have a Generation 8, Archos 70, here's the link you want: http://forum.archosfans.com/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=42067  All you have to do is open the apk file on your tablet.